# Stop re-rendering the react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using a third party component that re-renders every time state changes which is good but in some instances I do not want it to re-render even if the state changes. Is there a way to do using react functional component. I have read online and it says use shouldComponentUpdate() but I am trying to use functional component and tried using React.Memo but it still re-renders

Code

```
const getCustomers = React.memo((props) => {

useEffect(() => {

});

return (
<>
<ThirdPartyComponent>
do other stuff 
{console.log("Render Again")}
</ThirdPartyComponent>

</>
)
});
```

Comment: `...but in some instances I do not want it to re-render even if the state changes...` this defeats the entire purpose of React. It seems like an XY problem, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to hold rendering in which situation? It's a pretty unusual usecase but still valid

Comment: @Dupocas Yes, I want to stop re-rendering in some instances because I am getting an error using another library that unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.

Comment: Can you enrich your question or post a sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For props:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate)

**How do I implement shouldComponentUpdate?**

You can wrap a function component with React.memo to shallowly compare its props:

```
const Button = React.memo((props) => {
  // your component
});
```

It’s not a Hook because it doesn’t compose like Hooks do. React.memo is equivalent to PureComponent, but it only compares props. (You can also add a second argument to specify a custom comparison function that takes the old and new props. If it returns true, the update is skipped.)

**For state:**

There's no build in way to achieve this, but you can try to extract your logic to a custom hook. Here's my attempt to only rerender when shouldUpdate returns true. Use it with caution, because it's the opposite of what React was designed for:

```
const useShouldComponentUpdate = (value, shouldUpdate) => {
  const [, setState] = useState(value);
  const ref = useRef(value);

  const renderUpdate = (updateFunction) => {
    if (!updateFunction instanceof Function) {
      throw new Error(
        "useShouldComponentUpdate only accepts functional updates!"
      );
    }

    const newValue = updateFunction(ref.current);

    if (shouldUpdate(newValue, ref.current)) {
      setState(newValue);
    }

    ref.current = newValue;
    console.info("real state value", newValue);
  };

  return [ref.current, renderUpdate];
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
  const [count, setcount] = useShouldComponentUpdate(
    0,
    (value, oldValue) => value % 4 === 0 && oldValue % 5 !== 0
  );
```

In this case, a rerender would occur (due to usages of `setcount`) if, and only if, `shouldUpdate` returns true. i.e., when value is multiple of 4 and the previous value is not multiple of 5. Play with my [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-butterfly-kwz2n?file=/src/App.js) to see if that's really what you want.